# LEN function in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I am testing to use LEN function to count the length of the string in cell F2, as well as using FIND function for cell F4 however the s/s doesn't give me valid answers (I can count them manually). What would be wrong? TY

[Testing LEN function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKbGY.png)

[Testing FIND function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZcFX.png)

Comment: Select `Column_E` in your sheet & *apply this* from the menu ***Format*** > ***Number*** > ***Automatic***